# Solving a set of 2nd order differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a set of 2nd order differential equations. I have searched on the internet but haven't found a way to solve them. The equations were generated as a result of analysis of a coupled-pendulum system.

Here I want to solve equations $(1.9)$ and $(1.10)$

> $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \ddot{\theta}_1 + \frac{\left(m_1 g + kL_1 - L_1 m_1 \dot{\theta_1}^2\right)\sin{\theta_1} - kL_2 \sin{\theta_2}}{L_1 m_1 \cos{\theta_1}} &= 0 \tag{1.9} \\
> \ddot{\theta}_2 + \frac{\left(m_2 g + kL_2 - L_2 m_2 \dot{\theta_2}^2\right)\sin{\theta_2} - kL_1 \sin{\theta_1}}{L_2 m_2 \cos{\theta_2}} &= 0 \tag{1.10} \\
> \end{align}
> $$

with initial conditions given by

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \theta_1(t=0) &= \theta_{10}\\
> \theta_2(t=0) &= \theta_{20}\\
> v_1(t=0) &= v_{10}\\
> v_2(t=0) &= v_{20}\\
> \end{align} \tag{1.11}
> $$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum and something  called as Runge kutta method

Comment: The comment of @Aditya Garg deals with **numerical** solutions. But you are maybe looking for exact solutions (I don't know if there are some).

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an exact solution something in the form of sinusoidal function(if it exists in this form) or any other function.

Comment: The Wiki page states: "It is not possible to go further and integrate these equations analytically". Look at some examples in that link; the solution tends to be very chaotic.